# Timestamp accuracy failure

Tags: java, sql-server, timestamp

In the following code:

```
public static void assertEquals(Timestamp expected, Timestamp actual) {
    assertTrue(Math.abs(expected.getTime() - actual.getTime()) <= 5);
}
```

5 represents a 5ms accuracy on the expected vs actual time.

This code failed for the following input parameters:

```
expected:<2012-10-10 03:07:00.169>
actual:  <2012-10-10 03:07:00.17>
```

My question is why did the test expression in 'asserTrue' fail for those parameters and what is a better way to rewrite it such that it won't fail next time?

Comment: Are you using a java.sql.Timestamp? Also, print out the actual values of getTime() and show us the format youre using to print timestamps.

Comment: Assuming it is a `java.sql.Timestamp` and the dates are those from the `toString()` method, the result of `getTime()` for the given dates are 1349831220169 and 1349831220170. However, the test passes if I execute it on my machine.

Comment: All time operations have the inaccuracy of about 16ms on Windows, on \*nix systems it's less (about five-ish but can be more) except for `System.nanoTime()` which will be exact on a single core system and, umm, *weird* on multi core machines.

Use a bigger delta.

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases don't store times with millisecond precision. For example, `datetime` in MSSQL is [always rounded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) to increments of .000, .003 or .007 seconds.

Comment: Yes, it is java.sql.Timestamp. Unfortunately, I do not have the getTime() value but I see it was calculated by moeso. The system it failed on was Windows.

Comment: The database was MSSQL. Thank you Jesper.

Comment: Does it fail all the time or just sometimes?